# Неизвестные значения в массиве

Tags: c++-cli

Добрый день)
При отправке команды в массиве char sim[300]; через раз появляются непонятные символы из предыдущих запросов, не смотря на то что каждый раз  при отправке команды весь массив =0 (memset(sim, 0, sizeof(sim));)
Как быть куда смотреть? если посмотреть снифером что передается по USB то там только верные значения, то есть проблема в само программе!

```
private: System::Void ReadBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {

memset(sim, 0, sizeof(sim));
if (printer.TryConnection())
{


    PrinterTypeLB->Text = DeviceNameCB->Text;

    printer.SendComand(Firmware); 
    FirmwareLB->Text = gcnew String(sim);


    printer.SendComand(BoardRevision);
    BoardRevisionLB->Text = System::Convert::ToString(sim[0]);


    printer.SendComand(Temperature);
    HeadTempLB->Text = System::Convert::ToString(sim[0]) + " C°";


    printer.SendComand(CountCuted);
    value = string(sim);
    value.replace(value.end() - 4, value.end(), "");
    CutCounterLB->Text = gcnew System::String(value.c_str());

    printer.SendComand(PrintedPaper);
    value = string(sim);
    value.replace(value.end() - 2, value.end(), "");
    PrintedPaperLB->Text = gcnew System::String(value.c_str());

    printer.SendComand(PowerCounter);
    value = string(sim);
    value.replace(value.end() - 2, value.end(), "");
    PowerCounterLB->Text = gcnew System::String(value.c_str());


    printer.SendComand(SerialNumb);
    SerialLB->Text = gcnew String(sim);


    printer.SendComand(RetractCounter);

    value = string(sim);
    value.replace(value.end() - 3, value.end(), "");
    RetractCounterLB->Text = gcnew System::String(value.c_str());

}
else
    FalseConnection();
}

void SendComand(byte byt[]) {
    connectedStatus = CreatePrinter(n);
    if (connectedStatus) {
        try {
            memset(sim, 0, sizeof(sim));
            OVERLAPPED OverlapWrite;
            OverlapWrite.OffsetHigh = 1;
            OverlapWrite.Offset = 1;
            OverlapWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

            OVERLAPPED OverlapRead;
            OverlapRead.OffsetHigh = 1;
            OverlapRead.Offset = 1;
            OverlapRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);


            int sizebyt = sizeof(byt)-1;

            //Пишем
            bool sucsses = WriteFile(ConDevice, (LPCVOID)byt, sizebyt, &ReturnedLength, &OverlapWrite);

            ReturnedLength = 0;
            //Читаем

            sucsses = ReadFile(ConDevice, &sim, sizeof(sim), &ReturnedLength, &OverlapRead);

            //CloseHandle(ConDevice);
            throw std::exception();
            Sleep(20);
        }
        catch (const std::exception err) 
        {

        }
    }

}
```

[image: Неправильно][image: Правильно]